# update mysql database (DDT-groupname)

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, sql-update

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=root;" + "pwd=password;database=ddt_data");

conn.Open();
string command = "Update `fixture` SET `referee`=@referee, `ScoreA`=@ScoreA, `ScoreB`=@ScoreB, `Winner`=@Winner WHERE idfixture=" + Request.QueryString["idfixture"];
MySqlCommand update = new MySqlCommand(command, conn);

update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@referee", this.txtRef.Text);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scorea", this.txtScoreA.Text);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scoreb", this.txtScoreB.Text);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@winner", this.txtWinner.Text);

update.ExecuteNonQuery(); // use this if you don't need the DataReader
conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();
```

Comment: why are there single quotes around your column names..? also what is the problem and or issue.. you are not asking a question at all if you are getting any `SqlExceptions` then please post the error(s) also wrap your Sql Objects around a `using(){}` so that you do not have to explicitly call the Close and Dispose

Comment: the problem is that the system doesnt crash and the data does not get updated, i will remove the single qoutes and run.

Comment: in the pageload, i have a select statement that populates the textboxes , i had to include single quotes for it to work

Comment: change your sql string to the following 
`string command = "Update fixture SET referee =@referee," + 
                 "ScoreA = @ScoreA, ScoreB = @ScoreB, Winner = @Winner " + 
      "WHERE idfixture= " + Request.QueryString["idfixture"];` also wrap the code around a `try{}catch{SqlException sqlEx}`

Comment: also if  you are not sure on how to configure the connection string using `MySql` then take a look here at this link [C# ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql)

Comment: thanks but it was not successful

Comment: what does that mean.. do you know how to use the debugger..? if so step through the code.. also are you sure that it's even connecting to the database.. you need to post the updated code that you have tried..

Comment: also make sure that teh `idFixture` value is being evaluated properly can you tell me what the value of the `Request.QueryString["idfixture"]` is when you run the debugger.. can you show how that value is being assigned as well can't help you if you don't show all relevant code..

Answer (score 0):

```
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=root;" + "pwd=password;database=ddt_data");
        conn.Open();
        try
        {

            string command = "Update fixture SET referee =@referee," + "ScoreA = @ScoreA, ScoreB = @ScoreB, Winner = @Winner " + "WHERE idfixture= " + Request.QueryString["idfixture"];
            MySqlCommand update = new MySqlCommand(command, conn);
            update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@referee", this.txtRef.Text);
            update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scorea", this.txtScoreA.Text);
            update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scoreb", this.txtScoreB.Text);
            update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@winner", this.txtWinner.Text);
            update.ExecuteNonQuery(); // use this if you don't need the DataReader
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: heres the code , does accept the id, and is connected

Comment: what `Database` are you using..? make sure that you have GRANT RIGHTS for `INSERTS, UPDATE` for the Sql User... also do not post this code as an answer if it does not work.. this should be placed in the original question that you posted by editing your original question